# Insert context menu in Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, vuejs3, vue-options-api

I want to ask about Vue 3, how to insert a custom context menu in a Leaflet map?
I'm using leaflet@1.9.4, @vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet@0.10.1 and trying to use leaflet-contextmenu@1.4.0.
My code looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="map">
        <l-map ref="map" v-model:zoom="zoom" :center="[49.2265592, 16.5957531]">
            <l-tile-layer
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                layer-type="base"
                name="OpenStreetMap"
            ></l-tile-layer>
        </l-map>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { LMap, LTileLayer } from "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet";
// import L from 'leaflet';
// import "leaflet-contextmenu";

export default {
    components: {
        LMap,
        LTileLayer,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            zoom: 13,
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
L.map.contextmenu = true;
L.map.contextmenuItems = [{
    text: 'Show coordinates',
}];
```

However, I can't figure out how and where to write this.
Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to use leaflet-contextmenu@1.4.0 in @vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet@0.10.1.
The key is passing `options` (`:options="mapOptions"`) to the leaflet map constructor, which can be done declaratively.
The code is like:

```
<template>
    <div class="map">
        <l-map ref="map" v-model:zoom="zoom" :center="[49.2265592, 16.5957531]" :options="mapOptions">
            <l-tile-layer
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                layer-type="base"
                name="OpenStreetMap"
            ></l-tile-layer>
        </l-map>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import { LMap, LTileLayer } from "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet";
import 'leaflet-contextmenu';
import 'leaflet-contextmenu/dist/leaflet.contextmenu.min.css';

export default {
    components: {
        LMap,
        LTileLayer,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            zoom: 13,
            mapOptions: {
                contextmenu: true,
                contextmenuWidth: 140,
                contextmenuItems: [
                {
                    text: 'Show coordinates',
                    callback: ()=> alert('Coordinates callback')
                }
                ]
            },
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cant tell you much about `@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet` directly, since I never used it. However, you said "Any feedback would be appreciated.", so I'd like to present you a slightly different approach.
Usually I include Leaflet directly in my Vue Apps like this:

First I create a `ref` to my map element - just like you did:

```html
<div ref="mapEl"></div>
```

Then I get that ref using Vues `ref` function:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
const mapEl = ref();
```

You can pass the refs value - which contains the `HTMLElement` - directly in Leaflets constructor. I'm doing this right in the `onMounted` hook

```js
const map = leaflet.map(mapEl.value, {
    contextmenu: true,
    contextmenuWidth: 140,
    contextmenuItems: [
      {
        text: 'Show coordinates',
        callback: ()=> alert('Coordinates callback')
      }
    ]
});
// Other options you want to apply
```

Don't forget to import Leaflet and the contextmenu plugin:

```js
import leaflet from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-contextmenu';
import 'leaflet-contextmenu/dist/leaflet.contextmenu.min.css';
```

The full code could look like this:

```
<template>
  <div ref="mapEl"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import leaflet from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-contextmenu';
import 'leaflet-contextmenu/dist/leaflet.contextmenu.min.css';

const mapEl = ref();

onMounted(()=> {
const map = leaflet.map(mapEl.value, {
  contextmenu: true,
  contextmenuWidth: 140,
  contextmenuItems: [
    {
      text: 'Show coordinates',
      callback: ()=> alert('Coordinates callback')
    }
  ]
});
// Other options you want to apply
});
</script>
```

I hope this will solve your problem. Good luck on your app! :)

Comment: Have you tried this example, exactly how did you post it? It does not work on my side (no context menu).

Comment: @DaBler possibly chatgpt. It has that feel to it and bounties these days are attracting a lot of that trash

Comment: I copy-pasted it from one of my projects, but removed any non-neccessary parts to keep it simple. The context menu code is yours. Do you get any error message?

Comment: No error message in vue nor javascript console. The browser's context menu will appear instead of the custom context menu.

Comment: I just checked the Leaflet docs and it looks like it doen't provide custom context menus. Where do you get this snippet from? Do you use another lib or Vue component for this? However I found this: Leaflet triggers an MouseEvent both on mobile and desktop. You could use it to trigger your own menu: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-contextmenu

Comment: I already wrote it in the question: I am trying to use leaflet-contextmenu@1.4.0. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-contextmenu

Comment: Oops, sorry. Seems like I overread it. I implemented it locally on my app and it works like a charm. I just updated my answer. However: Be careful. This Package seems not to be maintained anymore. The last update was 6 years ago. Also the typescript bindings don't work correctly.

Comment: This works. However, it is not @vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet@0.10.1. Anyhow, your solution helped me a lot. Thank you.